# Try Except Limited Loop, python

Tags: python

Basically I was try to limit a loop to be only 30 times and if a condition satisfy the loop, than break it

```
import numpy as np
import time

for i in np.arange(30):
    a = 0
    try:
        b = 10 / a
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        a += 1
        time.sleep(5)
    else:
        print("success")
        break
```

result:

```
division by zero
division by zero
division by zero
...
```

This code keeps printing the Error, but shouldn't be able to stop at the 2nd run when a+=1 make a = 1 and no longer being "devision by zero"?

Comment: If you sprinkle some print functions in your code, you'll quickly find out what's the problem. Please debug your code.

Comment: You assign a = 0 inside the loop

Comment: At the beginning of each loop, you set the value of a = 0. This causes the exception to occur each time. Move it outside the for loop.

Comment: Yeah, that was on purpose for a= 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`a = 0` should be outside of the loop. In your code, `a` gets set to 0 on every iteration.

```py
import numpy as np
import time

a = 0
for i in np.arange(30):
    try:
        b = 10 / a
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        a += 1
        time.sleep(5)
    else:
        print("success")
        break
```

Comment: Right! How did I miss that! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
from time import sleep
a = 0
for i in range(30):
    try:
        b = 10 / a
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        a += 1
        sleep(5)
    else:
        print("success")
        break
```

- You should set the value of `a = 0` outside the `for` loop.
- It is not necessary to use `numpy` arrays for simple for loops. Simply use
  the `range()` function.
- Try not to import entire packages wherever possible. Importing entire packages increases latency (in bigger projects). Here you require only the sleep function. So use the statement from time import sleep.